# UIWebView interact with SMS application 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, url-scheme

I have an app that uses UIWebView to load a page. I have a SMS button on that site. How can I have Xcode read that button and open the iPhone SMS client once you click on that button?

Answer (score 1):

[SMS application URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/ipad/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html):

```
<a href="sms:">Launch SMS Application</a>
<a href="sms:1-954-555-1212">New SMS Message</a>
```